# Is the ring $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ Cohen-Macaulay? Does the dimension formula hold?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension, cohen-macaulay

Let $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a Noetherian, commutative ring, $A$. Is the polynomial ring Cohen-Macaulay?

If not, does it follow the dimension formula, 
$
\mathrm{dim} (A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]) = \mathrm{dim} (A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{p}) + \mathrm{ht} (\mathfrak{p} ),
$
for a prime ideal, $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: It depends on A, of course: take, for example, $n=0$.

Comment: If A satisfies the dimension formula is assumed, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It's well known that $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is CM iff $A$ is CM.
2. Let $A=\mathbb Z_{(2)}$. Then $\dim\mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]=2$, $\dim\mathbb Z_{(2)}[X]/(2X-1)=0$ and $\operatorname{ht}(2X-1)=1$.

Comment: related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369700/when-will-ax-1-ldots-x-n-satisfy-the-dimension-formula