# When will $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ satisfy the dimension formula?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, krull-dimension

> What property should $A$ satisfy so that $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$  satisfies the dimension formula,
>   $$\mathrm{dim}(A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]) = \mathrm{dim}(A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\mathfrak{p}) + \mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak{p}),$$ for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$?

For instance, this property holds when $A$ is a field. Is there a general property that ensures this formula is satisfied?

Comment: Even $A$ regular isn't enough as I pointed out in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1369644/121097). It certainly holds for $A$ a field.

Comment: looks like my question was answered already ? -- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49136/operatornameheight-mathfrakp-dim-a-mathfrakp-dim-a/49285#49285